# Redis as a MySQL engine?

Tags: mysql, redis, rdbms, mysql-proxy

Are there any existing efforts which fake a Redis server as a special type of MySQL engine?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE key_value_pairs (
    id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(30), 
    VALUE VARCHAR(200)
) ENGINE = REDIS;
```

So data could be directly `JOIN`'ed together, or doing all kind of calculations and transformations under SQL queries.

Or something act behind MySQL-Proxy?

Does something similar exist?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could run SQLite on a RAM disk?

Comment: You might be interested in the MEMORY storage engine.  Not Redis, but the performance is pretty good.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell what it really lacks though is persistence. Redis' persistence model is awesome if you need some persistence but not very strict. in the MEMORY engine you have to take care of that by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay,

MySQL 5.6 now has has memcached

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/news-5-6-6.html

shame it's not redis though.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I'm aware of, but you have two alternatives:

1. There is a very interesting project that is a fork of redis that
   added an SQL engine on top that is mostly SQL compliant and adds
   some redis goodies, it's called Alchemy DB:  http://code.google.com/p/alchemydatabase/

   IIRC
   I've discussed the option of writing a MySQL backend using redis
   with this project's author, but he had his reasons not to do it.
2. There are a few ORM frameworks that support redis as a backend, so
   you can model your schema on top of redis. I've written one but
   sadly it's not opened yet, and it also supports synchronizing data
   between the two, if you have tables that mirror what's going on in
   redis. I hope to open it soon when it stabilizes.

Comment: please could you share (if possible) why the author of redis though it to not be a good idea.

Comment: I cannot speak for Salvatore, but there is already a NoSQL store pluggable as a MySQL engine. It is called NDB, and is part of the MySQL Cluster package. I doubt a simple engine based on Redis would do better than that.